# Cause for Expected end of statement -error in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am learning VB.net and found this could and tried to run it, but keeps telling me "Expected end of statement".

```
Dim TestHex As String 
' Returns 5.
TestHex = Hex(5)
' Returns A.
TestHex = Hex(10)
' Returns 1CB.
TestHex = Hex(459)
```

The code can't be any simpler and clearer, but there is something I don't understand. Could you please explain it to me why it gives that kind of error? Tried few other codes and tells me the same thing.

Thanks

Comment: This code looks fine to me. Is it in a Module or Form? Have you tried debugging to find which statement is causing the error?

Comment: How are you trying to run this code?  Is this all of the code or do you have this code in a in a Method?  If you create a new console application in Visual Studio, it should create a Main method for you to place this code in.  That method will have an End Sub to specify the end of the method.

Comment: This is probably not the code that is causing the error. Try to find the relevant code what is underlined in visual studio?

Comment: This snippet is an example from MSDN for `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Hex()` in .Net, but it runs successfully even in VBA.

Comment: That's all the code and got it somewhere on the net. I ran it through the CMD console as well as the program called VbsEdit. Both give the same error. Have no form code. C'est tous!

Comment: The problem is not just this. What ever code I get from the net and try to run, I get EITHER" Expected ')' " OR "Expected end of statement". So something might be wrong with my environment? I use only window's cmd console and VbsEdit for running these.